# Asp.net enable/disable checkboxList with jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have this kind of structure:

**Radio Buttons:**

o Enable o Disable

**Check Boxes**

[]checkBox1

[]checkBox2

[]checkBox3

[]checkBox4

The Above controls are generated dynamically.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rbSubsidiaries" onclick = "Radio_Click()"/>

 <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="cblSubsidiaries" Enabled="False"/>
```

**What I want is**: When the user click on the RadioButton **Enable** All the  checkboxes get enable otherwise disable.

I am at the point where I can see that if the user has clicked on enable radio button.

```
 function Radio_Click() {
 if ($('#<%=rbSubsidiaries.ClientID %> input:checked').val() == 'enable') {
            alert('enable is clicked');
}
}
```

But I don't know how to enable all the **checkBoxes**.

Picture that Contains the the rendered structure of the CheckBoxList. First Two check Boxes.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("#cblSubsidiaries > input[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled", false)
```

Update:

```
$("#contentpage_0_content_0_cblSubsidiaries input[type=checkbox]").prop("disabled",false)
```

Comment: Can you show the rendered structure of the CheckBoxList?

Comment: Thanks @Bubavanhalen :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the code which will help you

**Html**

```
<input type="radio" name="check" value="enable" class="enableList">Enable
    <input type="radio" name="check" value="disable" class="disableList">Disable    

<div class="container">
 <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car </div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {           
        $('.enableList').change(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
                $('.container').find('input:checkbox').each(function () {
                    alert ("enable check box");
                });
            }
        });


        $('.disableList').change(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
                $('.container').find('input:checkbox').each(function () {
                    alert("disable check box");
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

this is working fidler
https://jsfiddle.net/Ln7y6v0n/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$('#contentpage_0_content_0_cblSubsidiaries input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID%>').change(function () {
                 $('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID%>').each(function () {
                     var checked = $(this).find('input:radio:checked');
                     if (checked.val() == "Enable") {

                         $('#<%=CheckBoxList1.ClientID%>').each(function () {
                             var checked = $(this).find('input:checkbox');
                             checked.prop('checked', true);
                         });
                     }
                     else {

                         $('#<%=CheckBoxList1.ClientID%>').each(function () {
                             var checked = $(this).find('input:checkbox');
                             checked.prop('checked', false);
                         });
                     }
                 });
             });
        });

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListItem item = new ListItem();
            item.Text = "Enable";
            item.Value = "Enable";
            RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(item);

            ListItem item1 = new ListItem();
            item1.Text = "Disable";
            item1.Value = "Disable";
            RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(item1);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                ListItem chkitem = new ListItem();
                chkitem.Text = "Checkbox" + i;
                chkitem.Value = "Checkbox" + i;
                CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(chkitem);
            }

        }
```

```html
 <div>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
            <br />
            <hr />
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
        </div>
```