# CheckboxList Check and Uncheck in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have three Checkbox List which is bounded with list from database. Values taken from the database is distinct values. After checkboxes were bound with data I have to choose a checkbox. If I select a checkbox from first checkboxlist category it should show matched value in the second and third checkbox list.

Example:

```
CheckboxList 1:
1.100
2.200
3.300
4.400

CheckboxList 2:
1.powder
2.Capsule
3.gel

CheckboxList 3:
1.10
2.30
3.30
```

If I select 100 from checkboxlist 1 then it should enable only powder and capsule from checkboxlist2 and enable 10 from checkboxlist 3 and disable others and if I select multiple selection from checkbox 1 it should enable checkboxes depending on selection.

Comment: For that, You have to write Multiple IF condition to check the dependent values in two different checkboxes.

Comment: yes I dunno how to do...because everything should work without refreshing

Comment: I think you can get help from this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778487/asp-net-enable-disable-checkboxlist-with-jquery

Comment: With dependent checkboxes, one possible solution is re-evaluate the following based on the options above, meaning, if you select 100, onClick, repopulate the second box with data only applicable, and so forth, like this, only related options will show depending on the previous selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with JavaScript (I used jQuery) to avoid refreshing the page.

I defined a sort of matrix corresponding of the different choices you have for the first checkbox list.

A change (a checkbox checked) in the first checkbox list triggers a function that get all the checkbox checked from this checkbox list. Then get the values checked, for example `01` gets the corresponding choices in the matrix `matrix["01"]`: `0|1`; the second checkbox list will have the checkbox at index `0` enabled and the third checkbox list will have the checkbox at index `1` enabled.

**There's an HTML version you can try/run at the bottom of my answer.**

You can try the following code in a WebForm:

ASPX:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" onchange="manageCheckboxList();" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="100"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="200"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="300"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="400"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<hr />

<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList2" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Powder"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Capsule"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Gel"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<hr />

<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList3" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="10"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="20"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="30"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
function manageCheckboxList() {
    // Get checkbox checked from first checkbox list
    var checked = $('#CheckBoxList1').find('input:checked');

    // Check if there's a least one checkbox checked
    if (checked.length > 0) {
        var matrix = {}
        matrix["0"] = "01|0";
        matrix["1"] = "12|01";
        matrix["2"] = "2|2";
        matrix["3"] = "1|0";
        matrix["01"] = "0|1";
        matrix["02"] = "0|2";
        matrix["03"] = "1|1";
        matrix["12"] = "1|2";
        matrix["13"] = "0|2";
        matrix["23"] = "12|12";
        matrix["012"] = "012|012";
        matrix["013"] = "012|012";
        matrix["023"] = "01|01";
        matrix["123"] = "12|02";
        matrix["0123"] = "012|012";

        var result = "";

        // Construct result
        $(checked).each(function () {
            result += $(this).val();
        });

        var subchoices = matrix[result].split('|');

        // Update Checkbox list 2 and 3
        updateCheckboxList($("#CheckBoxList2"), subchoices[0], false);
        updateCheckboxList($("#CheckBoxList3"), subchoices[1], false);
    } else {
        // Reset checkbox
        updateCheckboxList($("#CheckBoxList2"), null, false);
        updateCheckboxList($("#CheckBoxList3"), null, false);
    }
}

function updateCheckboxList(el, subchoices, disableCheckboxList) {
    var checkboxList = $(el).find("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxList.length; i++) {
        if (subchoices != null) {
            var disabled = true;

            if (subchoices.indexOf($(checkboxList[i]).val()) >= 0) {
                disabled = false;
            }

            $(checkboxList[i]).prop("disabled", disabled);
        } else {
            $(checkboxList[i]).prop("disabled", false);
        }
    }

    $(el).prop("disabled", disableCheckboxList);
}
```

Please try the following snippet (in HTML instead of ASPX) to view the result:

```js
function manageCheckboxList() {
    // Get checkbox checked from first checkbox list
    var checked = $('#CheckBoxList1').find('input:checked');

    // Check if there's a least one checkbox checked
    if (checked.length > 0) {
        var matrix = {}
        matrix["0"] = "01|0";
        matrix["1"] = "12|01";
        matrix["2"] = "2|2";
        matrix["3"] = "1|0";
        matrix["01"] = "0|1";
        matrix["02"] = "0|2";
        matrix["03"] = "1|1";
        matrix["12"] = "1|2";
        matrix["13"] = "0|2";
        matrix["23"] = "12|12";
        matrix["012"] = "012|012";
        matrix["013"] = "012|012";
        matrix["023"] = "01|01";
        matrix["123"] = "12|02";
        matrix["0123"] = "012|012";

        var result = "";

        // Construct result
        $(checked).each(function () {
            result += $(this).val();
        });

        var subchoices = matrix[result].split('|');

        // Update Checkbox list 2 and 3
        updateCheckboxList($("#CheckBoxList2"), subchoices[0], false);
        updateCheckboxList($("#CheckBoxList3"), subchoices[1], false);
    } else {
        // Reset checkbox
        updateCheckboxList($("#CheckBoxList2"), null, false);
        updateCheckboxList($("#CheckBoxList3"), null, false);
    }
}

function updateCheckboxList(el, subchoices, disableCheckboxList) {
    var checkboxList = $(el).find("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxList.length; i++) {
        if (subchoices != null) {
            var disabled = true;

            if (subchoices.indexOf($(checkboxList[i]).val()) >= 0) {
                disabled = false;
            }

            $(checkboxList[i]).prop("disabled", disabled);
        } else {
            $(checkboxList[i]).prop("disabled", false);
        }
    }

    $(el).prop("disabled", disableCheckboxList);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="CheckBoxList1" onchange="manageCheckboxList();">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="CheckBoxList1_0" type="checkbox" value="0" />
            <label for="CheckBoxList1_0">100</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="CheckBoxList1_1" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            <label for="CheckBoxList1_1">200</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="CheckBoxList1_2" type="checkbox" value="2" />
            <label for="CheckBoxList1_2">300</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="CheckBoxList1_3" type="checkbox" value="3" />
            <label for="CheckBoxList1_3">400</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<hr />

<table id="CheckBoxList2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="CheckBoxList2_0" type="checkbox" value="0" />
            <label for="CheckBoxList2_0">Powder</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="CheckBoxList2_1" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            <label for="CheckBoxList2_1">Capsule</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="CheckBoxList2_2" type="checkbox" value="2" />
            <label for="CheckBoxList2_2">Gel</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<hr />

<table id="CheckBoxList3">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="CheckBoxList3_0" type="checkbox" value="0" />
            <label for="CheckBoxList3_0">10</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="CheckBoxList3_1" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            <label for="CheckBoxList3_1">20</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="CheckBoxList3_2" type="checkbox" value="2" />
            <label for="CheckBoxList3_2">30</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Initially all the checkbox should be enabled...Thank you for your time.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer: all checkbox list are enabled at start and when resetting (no checkbox checked in the first checkbox list).